# Check whether string includes some substring of another string - the easiest way

Tags: javascript

Clarification - I want to check if str1 and str2 share common substring.

str1 = "and we know that the lion"
str2 = "the lion is big"

by using those two string because the lion happens to show on both string then true will be invoked.

Thanks.

Comment: Show some code what you have tried so far

Comment: tried using with includes and substring but failed. guessing regex maybe.

Comment: @HarelYacovian post the code you tired. along with question

Comment: `const f = (s, t) => [...s].some(e => [...t].reduce((p,c) => (p[c] = true, p), {})[e]);` and while this answers what you literally asked, i dont think it's what you actually want. (and yes, i was too lazy to add a variable to not recreate that object every single character)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) that will return a boolean value:

```js
console.log("and we know that the lion".includes("the lion is big")); // returns false
console.log("and we know that the lion".includes("the lion")); // returns true
```

Comment: It won't work again what I want here

Comment: @HarelYacovian Have you even tried it? `"and we know that the lion".includes("the lion is big")` works just fine!

Comment: Yes, I did!, but it returns false I don't want to check each substring of the second string until I find that it contains it.

Comment: @HarelYacovian: What do you mean by "each substring of the second string"?  It's not clear at all what you're asking.  If you want to know if one string includes another string, this answer shows that.  If that's not what you're asking, please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: The name of the method gives it away XD